# Renaming a new folder file to the next incremental number with powershell script

Tags: powershell

I would really appreciate your help with this
I should first mention that I have been unable to find any specific solutions and I am very new to programming with powershell, hence my request

I wish to write (and later schedule) a script in powershell that looks for a file with a specific name - RFUNNEL and then renames this to R0000001. There will only be one of such 'RFUNELL' files in the folder at any time. However when next the script is run and finds a new RFUNNEL file I will this to be renamed to R0000002 and so on and so forth

I have struggled with this for some weeks now and the seemingly similar solutions that I have come across have not been of much help - perhaps because of my admittedly limited experience with powershell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Others might be able to do this with less syntax, but try this:

```
$rootpath = "C:\derp"

if (Test-Path "$rootpath\RFUNNEL.txt")
{ $maxfile = Get-ChildItem $rootpath | ?{$_.BaseName -like "R[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]"} | Sort BaseName -Descending | Select -First 1 -Expand BaseName;
  if (!$maxfile) { $maxfile = "R0000000" }
  [int32]$filenumberint     = $maxfile.substring(1); $filenumberint++
  [string]$filenumberstring = ($filenumberint).ToString("0000000"); 
  [string]$newName          = ("R" + $filenumberstring + ".txt");

  Rename-Item "$rootpath\RFUNNEL.txt" $newName;
}
```

Comment: Hi Pdanke thanks for the reply. I have tried your suggestion but am getting the following error:             You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\test\code.ps1:5 char:49
+   [int32]$filenumberint     = $maxfile.substring <<<< (1); $filenumberint++
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (substring:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

Comment: Sorry pdanke, this worked like magic! I got an error the first time I ran the script but then realised that the file was actually renamed and the reason for the error was because the 'R000001' file had not existed. Thanks again!

Comment: Ah, yep I was expecting a file there.  Fixed.  You can mark it as answered if it worked out for you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative using regex:

```
[cmdletbinding()]
param()

$triggerFile   = "RFUNNEL.txt"
$searchPattern = "R*.txt"
$nextAvailable = 0

# If the trigger file exists
if (Test-Path -Path $triggerFile)
{
    # Get a list of files matching search pattern
    $files = Get-ChildItem "$searchPattern" -exclude "$triggerFile"

    if ($files)
    {
        # store the filenames in a simple array
        $files = $files | select -expandProperty Name 
        $files | Write-Verbose 

        # Get next available file by carrying out a 
        # regex replace to extract the numeric part of the file and get the maximum number
        $nextAvailable = ($files -replace '([a-z])(.*).txt', '$2' | measure-object -max).Maximum
    }

    # Add one to either the max or zero
    $nextAvailable++

    # Format the resulting string with leading zeros    
    $nextAvailableFileName = 'R{0:000000#}.txt' -f $nextAvailable
    Write-Verbose "Next Available File: $nextAvailableFileName"

    # rename the file
    Rename-Item -Path $triggerFile -NewName $nextAvailableFileName
}
```